# How to fix error on `import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart'` on Flutter project?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I created a Flutter project, and I have an error on the line:

```
import package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart
```

I already followed this structure from [flutter_svg documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg#-installing-tab-).

It does not get identified on VS Code and Android Studio.

Any solution for this?

[image: image description here]

This is my **pubspec.yaml**

```
name: first_project
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
flutter_svg: ^0.18.0
google_fonts: ^1.0.0
flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.

cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter



# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/svg/

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: Try adding your dependencies below `cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2`..that might also work..let me know if it worked for you :)

Comment: Did it work..!?

Comment: @srikanth7785 no  its not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always remember, indentation plays a huge deal in `pubspec.yaml` files. Anyway, your dependencies in `pubspec.yaml` should look something like this:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_svg: ^0.18.0
  google_fonts: ^1.0.0
  flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this package on the terminal

```
flutter pub add flutter_svg
```